# check current time between time interval android

Tags: android, time

I want to create an app that will allow the user to check whether or not the current time falls between a specified time interval. More specifically, I created a sql table using sqllite program, with the table specifying an end time and a start time for each record. The problem is that the type of data each field can be is limited to text, number, and other type other than a datetime type. So, how would I be able to check if the current time is between the start and end time since the format of time is in h:mm and not just an integer value that I could just do less than or greater than? Do I have to convert the current time to minutes?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the comparison even if time is not stored in the datetime type, [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/403639/java/java/convert-data-type-string-timestamp) is a link that explains the conversion from string to time.

If that doesn't work, convert the time to seconds (int) and calculate the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can save and retrieve your time as String:

```
String to long: String.valueOf()
long to String: Long.valueOf()
```

Then, you use this procedure to check time:

```
//Time checker
private boolean timeCheck(long startTimeInput, long endTimeInput) {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if ((currentTime > startTimeInput) && (currentTime < endTimeInput)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;         
    }
}
```

And in your main program check it like this:

```
//You kept the times as String
if (timeCheck(Long.valueOf(start), Long.valueOf(end))) {
    //it is in the interval
} else {
    //not in the interval
}
```

I hope it helps.